# What does 'to make for spurious respect' mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I'm having trouble understanding these few lines:

*In recent decades, we've come to assume that respecting our fellow citizens' moral and religious convictions means ignoring them. But this stance of avoidance can **make for spurious respect**.*

What does '**to make for spurious respect**' mean? I guess 'spurious' here means 'non-genuine', but I am confused of how this fits in to the phrasal verb 'to make for'.

Comment: [*Spurious*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/spurious) has several different senses. There's nothing about its use here that makes it obvious that one sense is meant more than another. (*Smoking cigarettes in bed can **make for** a stressful period of rest if they catch fire*.)

Comment: “can make for” here means “can lead to” or “can result in”.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can make for *spurious* respect can mean nothing but imaginary or insincere respect. That is what the kids refer to as *ironic* these days. The phrase *to make for* is just as Jason  and Xanne say, *result in*, come to or *mean*.